# How to save to second table and before saving put it to first table

Tags: android, mysql, android-sqlite

Hello everybody Many days passed i read again a lot of examples and threads. But again i am newbie please dont kick me hard. I think question was not very good but i am going to explain i have 3 tables at android DB.
These are three tables

1. TABLE_ITEMS
2. TABLE_PRIHOD (it's input)
3. TABLE_RASHOD (it's output) of goods.

I want to use id_goods for all product names but i don't have practice.

now what I can, I have to save DB in different 2 tables and take them at different *listview*.

I want to save first all id_goods at TABLE_ITEMS and after save to TABLE_PRIHOD because i think if i have all goods name's easier to work at DB. I know I made it wrong.

**HERE is the Example**

- Save at TABLE_PRIHOD(Input) id 1 books 2014.02.12 500 pieces 2$.
- Before saving to TABLE_PRIHOD I want to save books to TABLE_ITEMS to have it as id_goods.
- Use it to TABLE_PRIHOD(Input) not write as books but to write its id from  TABLE_ITEMS.

**Its my Imagine** : 
(id)1 (id_goods)1 (date)2014.02.12. (amount)500 (cost)2

[***My full CODE is here in this LINK pastie***](http://pastie.org/8728845)

```
public class DBHandlerImpl extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements  DBHandler<Goods>{
     // all DB-variabls here


public DBHandlerImpl(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "create table " + TABLE_ITEMS + "(" + ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + ID_GOODS + " integer);";
    db.execSQL(query);

     query = "create table " + TABLE_PRIHOD + "(" + ID_PRIHOD + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                                                     GOODS + " TEXT, " +
                                                     DATE + " TEXT, " +
                                                     AMOUNT + " INTEGER, " +
                                                     COST + " INTEGER);";
    db.execSQL(query);

    query = "create table " + TABLE_RASHOD + "(" + ID_PRODANO + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
                                                    PRODANO + " TEXT, " +
                                                    PRODANO_DATE + " TEXT, " +
                                                    PRODANO_AMOUNT + " INTEGER, " +
                                                    PRODANO_COST + " INTEGER);";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i2) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ITEMS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRIHOD);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_RASHOD);
    onCreate(db);
}

@Override
public void addItemsId(Goods goods) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(GOODS, goods.getName_goods());
    db.insert(TABLE_ITEMS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

@Override
public void addPrihod(Goods goods) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 //   values.put(ID, goods.getId());
    values.put(GOODS, goods.getName_goods());
    values.put(DATE, goods.getDate());
    values.put(AMOUNT, goods.getAmount());
    values.put(COST, goods.getCost());
    db.insert(TABLE_PRIHOD, null, values);
    db.close();
}

@Override
public void addRashod(Goods goods) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(PRODANO, goods.getName_goods());
    values.put(PRODANO_DATE, goods.getDate());
    values.put(PRODANO_AMOUNT, goods.getAmount());
    values.put(PRODANO_COST, goods.getCost());
    db.insert(TABLE_RASHOD, null, values);
    db.close();
}
public class Prihod extends Activity{
     //all variables are here

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.prihod);
    //initialize code here 
    //findViewById also located here


}

public void saveTovar(View v){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Prihod.this);
    builder.setTitle("Потдвердить сохранение...");
    builder.setMessage("Вы уверены, что хотите сохранить?");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.save);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Да", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           goods = new Goods(1,edtTovar.getText().toString(),
                                editDate.getText().toString(),
                                editAmount.getText().toString(),
                                editCost.getText().toString());
            db.addPrihod(goods);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Новый товар сохранен!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Нет", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}`  `public class Rashod extends Activity{
private DBHandler<Goods> db;
private Goods goods;
private EditText editRashod;
private EditText editDateRashod;
private EditText editAmountRashod;
private EditText editCostRashod;
private Button btn_rashod_save;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.rashod);
    TextView textTovar = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textTovar);
    TextView textDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textDate);
    TextView textAmount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textAmount);
    TextView textCost = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCost);
    editRashod = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editRashod);
    editDateRashod = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDateRashod);
    editAmountRashod = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editAmountRashod);
    editCostRashod = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCostRashod);
    btn_rashod_save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_rashod_save);
    db = new DBHandlerImpl(this);
}
```

Comment: Oh man, a code with full history...!!!

Comment: i know therefore i need help please how to save first to TABLE_ITEM all goods and after to TABLE_PRIHOD maybe thee is another easier way

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to insert the goods to TABLE_ITEMS first, and then use the id of the inserted TABLE_ITEM record in TABLE_PRIHOD?

If so, you can return the inserted id in `addItemsId`, because `db.insert` returns the id of the newly inserted  row http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)

This would look something like this then

```
@Override
public long addItemsId(Goods goods) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(GOODS, goods.getName_goods());
    long goods_id = db.insert(TABLE_ITEMS, null, values);
    db.close();

    return goods_id;
}

@Override
public void addPrihod(Goods goods) {

    long goods_id = addItemsId(goods);
    // -1 means an error occured
    if(goods_id != -1){

        goods.setId(goods_id);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(ID_GOODS, goods_id);
        values.put(GOODS, goods.getName_goods());
        values.put(DATE, goods.getDate());
        values.put(AMOUNT, goods.getAmount());
        values.put(COST, goods.getCost());
        db.insert(TABLE_PRIHOD, null, values);
        db.close();
     }
}
```

Comment: brother thanks you understand what i want your answer will help me i hope i will try thanks

Comment: @suoer-qua Brother please help me one more time i changed at `public interface DBHandler<T> {
    public int addItemsId(T t);` to `public interface DBHandler<T> {
    public long addItemsId(T t);` errors on public class DBHandlerImpl extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements  DBHandler<Goods> solved now there is error on method public void addPrihod(Goods goods) i can't find error changed int to long to string but not solved

Comment: error is here  `goods.setId(goods_id); `  at method please what is wrong explain please `  @Override
    public void addPrihod(Goods goods) {
        long goods_id = addItemsId(goods);
        // -1 means an error occured
        if(goods_id != -1){
            goods.setId(goods_id);
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();`

Comment: `  values.put(ID, goods.getId());
            values.put(GOODS, goods.getName_goods());
            values.put(DATE, goods.getDate());
            values.put(AMOUNT, goods.getAmount());
            values.put(COST, goods.getCost());
            db.insert(TABLE_PRIHOD, null, values);
            db.close();
        }
    }`

Comment: note that you actually don't need `goods.setId(goods_id);`. Instead you can just change `values.put(ID, goods.getId());`to `values.put(ID, goods_id);`, since it looks like you're not processing the goods object any further

Comment: Brother thanks i found my error really i didn't change int to long and my second error was i didn't comment  public void addPrihod(Goods goods) there were 2 same methods now i am going to experiment thanks

Comment: sorry again interrupting i am newbie what else i can do i will ask someone who knows when i save something on TABLE_PRIHOD error is coming that there is no column goods i think it's not putting id from TABLE_ITEM here is log `02-13 16:02:48.727    8656-8656/uz.akrampulatov.app E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table items has no column named goods
02-13 16:02:48.737    8656-8656/uz.akrampulatov.app E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting goods=books
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table items has no column named goods (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO items(goods) VALUES (?)
`

Comment: `            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1013)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:624)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)`

Comment: ` at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
            at uz.akrampulatov.app.activity.db.DBHandlerImpl.addItemsId(DBHandlerImpl.java:74)
            at uz.akrampulatov.app.activity.db.DBHandlerImpl.addPrihod(DBHandlerImpl.java:83)
            at uz.akrampulatov.app.activity.db.DBHandlerImpl.addPrihod(DBHandlerImpl.java:12)
            at uz.akrampulatov.app.activity.Prihod$1.onClick(Prihod.java:58)`

Comment: ` at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)`

Comment: ` at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: That's because your `TABLE_ITEMS` does not have a column named goods. In your create table statement you add a column `ID_GOODS integer`, but in addItem you try to add `values.put(GOODS, goods.getName_goods());`. I suggest you edit your create table statement

Comment: brother sorry again for interrupting i tried to edit create table statement but not succeded please can you help? i don't want to say write everything for me, i just couldn't so i am asking for a help, please can you help me to write create table statement thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but if I post the whole code here it would not be helpful and this is not what stackoverflow is about. Anyway, I edited the code above. All you have to do is make sure that the columns you want to insert with `values.put()` are actually present in your create table statements. I suggest you check if every column you use in `values.put()` (like `ID_GOODS` for example) is included in your create table statement of the corresponding table.